# How to make list item in the center of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm confused why my list items is not really in center of the screen. The list items should be in the center of the screen if i use "align-items: center;" but it's not work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Anagram - Single Player</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(83,49,128,1) 0%, rgba(125,74,149,1) 35%, rgba(164,104,169,1) 100%);
            width:100vw; height:100vh;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .list {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            position:absolute;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            align-items: center;
            background: blue;
        }

        .list ul li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: black;
            width: 32px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 4px;
        }

        .list ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list">
        <ul id="button-list"></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        let ul = document.getElementById("button-list");
        let word = "MAMALIA";

        for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>" + word[i] + "</a>";
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have try using align items, justify content, and transform. I still can't make it really in the center of the screen.

Comment: its is center already https://imgur.com/a/oQotoal

Comment: @NAZIRHUSSAIN u can see the left and the right side space are not the same. The left side empty space is bigger than the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Just add padding: 0; in the ul.

 .list ul {
     padding: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Or, if padding is desired, they need to just make sure it's even on the right and left.